# How to change specific classname in react after click

Tags: reactjs

```js
checkCard(cardName, index) {
        const item = {
            name: cardName,
            indexNumber: index
        }; 
        
        // check the part where you should look at
        const newFlipStatus = this.state.flipped[index];

        this.setState({
            tempArray: [...this.state.tempArray, item],
            flipped: !newFlipStatus
        }, () => {
            this.cardCounter(this.state.tempArray)
        });
    }

render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <button onClick={() => this.shuffleCard()}>Click</button>
                {this.state.cardArray.map((items, index) => (
                    <li className={this.state.flipped ? 'card' : 'card true'} key={index} onClick={() => this.checkCard(items, index)}>{items}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When the user clicks on a specific card in this case a specific element, but the problem I have now is that it is looping through all the element and change them all.

https://codeshare.io/5O0M7j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.state = {
        memoryCards: ['mario', 'luigi', 'browser', 'peach', 'wario', 'toad', 'yoshi', 'bowser-junior', 'waluigi', 'diddy-kong-jr' ],
        cardArray: [],
        newArray: [],
        tempArray: [],
        arrayHere: [],
        count: 0,
        score: 0,
        flipped: false
    }
```

You only have a single `flipped` property which is representing the whole deck of cards. This is the same property you are checking in:

```
<li className={this.state.flipped ? 'card' : 'card true'}
```

So when you click on it, you update the state, but this state property is used on all the cards, so all the `li` elements will get the `card` classname.

Your check:

```
const newFlipStatus = this.state.flipped[index];
```

Will also return false, as you defined flipped as a boolean at the start. Then you assign it, which will be true.

```
flipped: !newFlipStatus
```

---

If you update your flipped state to an Object:

```
this.state = {
  flipped: {}
  ...
}
```

You can update your Render function to check the property, on the Flipped Object, which related to the Index of the card:

```
<li className={this.state.flipped[index] ? 'card' : 'card true'}....
```

And then within your checkCard Function, you can check can flip the value and reassign it to your Flipped Object:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  tempArray: [...state.tempArray, item],
  flipped: {
    ...state.flipped,
    [index]: !state.flipped[index]
  }
}), () => {
  this.cardCounter(this.state.tempArray)
});
```

Comment: Syntax of the last snippet contains a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated it now. I was missing a set of { }

Comment: Thanks your explanation was quite constructive, and clear. Have learned lot from your answer.